# Firebase JS Array losing scope

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase data is as follows

```
-users
--demo1
---conid:1
-election
--election1
---conRegex:1
--election2
---conRegex:1
```

the code to retrieve election1, election2 is

```
var conid;
    var conRegex;
    var electionArr = [];
    if(uidAnonymous != null) {
        db.ref('users/'+user).once('value', function(snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                conid = snapshot.val().conid;
            }
        });
        db.ref('election/').once('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(electionSnapshot) {
                conRegex = electionSnapshot.val().conRegex;
                if(conid.startsWith(conRegex)) {
                    electionArr.push(electionSnapshot.key.toString());
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(electionArr);
    }
```

Problem is electionArr is empty? How do i solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

Firebase function calls are `asynchronous`. Thats how it works you cannot assign an array from out of scope inside firebase `on` function call. Make your array available inside your `once(value)` function.

```
var conid;
var conRegex;
if(uidAnonymous != null) {
    db.ref('users/'+user).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()) {
            conid = snapshot.val().conid;
        }
    });
    db.ref('election/').once('value', function(snapshot) {
        var electionArr = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(electionSnapshot) {
            conRegex = electionSnapshot.val().conRegex;
            if(conid.startsWith(conRegex)) {
                Object.keys(electionSnapshot.val()).map(k => {
                    electionArr.push(electionSnapshot.val()[k]);
                })
            }
        });
        console.log(electionArr);
    });
}
```

Comment: i need electionArr outside the if(uidAnonymous != null) then how will i do that?

Comment: I have edited the code. You needs to map through keys of returned snapshot object and push values to array

Comment: I have edited the code tell me If data is coming in electionArr now or not then we try further. Because I am unable to check the output

Comment: Not getting the expected results that is the electionSnapshot.key

Comment: what do you mean by expected output. Are you even getting values in `electionSnapshot.val()`.

Comment: [election1, election2] is expected output. Your code gets the innermost values which i dont need

Answer (score 1):

The `once()` function [is asynchronous](https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93). You'll have to nest your reads and log your array to the console when all the data is read:

```
var conid;
var conRegex;
var electionArr = [];
if(uidAnonymous != null) {
    db.ref('users/'+user).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()) {
            conid = snapshot.val().conid;

            db.ref('election/').once('value', function(snapshot) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(electionSnapshot) {
                    conRegex = electionSnapshot.val().conRegex;
                    if(conid.startsWith(conRegex)) {
                        electionArr.push(electionSnapshot.key.toString());
                    }
                });
                console.log(electionArr);
            });
        }
    });
}
```